# Error: Provided address is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed, or its an indrect IBAN address which can't be converted?

Tags: solidity, transactions, blockchain

Can anybody please help me fix this error? I do not know why it happens:

> Error: Provided address is invalid, the capitalization
>   checksum test failed, or its an indrect IBAN address which can't be
>   converted

[image]

I tried it on remix and it works

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution changing the name of byte32 by string,I think it is a mistake of the plugin Etheratom. "Please excuse my limited English." You could add "Corrections are welcome"

Answer (score 0):

It it may help, I have the same error with the following function :

```
function addpartner(address partner, uint percent) {}
```

The error disappears if I switch the parameters :

```
function addpartner(uint percent, address partner) {}
```

It doesn't explain the error's origin, but you could try to switch your _a and _id parameters. May be a etheratom bug ?

Comment: in fact, I don't have the error anymore... with solidity 0.4.23 and last version of atom/etheratom. So, I am not sure it helps.

Comment: @ OlivierNerot I have tried, but not work. I found solution changing the name of byte32 by string